# c# combo box winform

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a combobox with the text 'select'.  I want to set it so that the user cannot type over that.  Currently they are able to.  I cannot see any read only option for this though.

Can any body advise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set its `DropDownStyle` property to `ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList`.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.comboboxstyle.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try setting  `DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList`

Answer (score 1):

If you want it for all items then

> ```
> set the ComboBox's DropDownStyle property to DropDownList.
> ```

If you want it for the 'Select' item alone then handle KeyDown of ComboBox
PS: I've --Select-- as the first item in ComboBox

```
 private void comboBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {

                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: That suppress keypress thing is a bit hacky. "Right-click, select-all, right-click, paste" will still work..

Answer (score 1):

Use DropDownStyle = DropDownList. Hope that helps.

Comment: Making Combobox "ReadOlny" is not always a good idea if you want autocomplete to work.

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
private void ComboBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```